# Action on Flag manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

When $G$ is of type A,D,E and $B_4$ then the group of Dynkin diagram automorphisms is non-trivial. If $B$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$, then is there a nice action of the Dynkin diagram automorphism group on $G/B$ ?